# Calcular distância entre 2 pontos no Google maps1

Tags: div

Olá um colega resolveu esse problema de calcular uma distancia no google maps,
a minha pergunta é. Como fazer uma multiplicação da quantidade de km do trajeto da pesquisa?, ou seja multiplicar o km e imprimir junto com o resultado do trajeto.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende fazer? A pergunta não é nada clara e está sem contexto.